# React not rendering if add edited object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code below works fine and react re-render the child:

```
const [equip, setEquip] = useState({biAbt:[]});
   const handleSet = (name, value) => {
   setEquip({[name]: value});
}
```

But if i try set the state with an object there is no render:

```
const [equip, setEquip] = useState({biAbt:[]});
const handleSet = (name, value) => {
   let obj = equip;
   obj[name] = value;
   setEquip(obj);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I need to add or update a property to the existing state object.

Comment: Try this --->  let obj = {...equip};

Comment: `let obj = equip;` is not doing what you think it is. In JavaScript objects and arrays are stored in variables by their references. Assigning it to a new variable simple assigns it the same reference. This means you're mutating the original state, and React does not think it needs to re-render.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Also see [why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really)

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `let obj = equip;` obj has the same reference as the previous state, so react will not re-render, you can you it like this instead:

```
const handleSet = (name, value) => {
   setEquip(equip => ({...equip, [name]: value}));
}
```

by spreading into a new object, a new reference will be created and react will re-render

Comment: Your function has a syntax error. You can't implicitly return an object without wrapping it in `( )`. Currently its trying to open a function body.

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks. The correct syntax  `setEquip((equip => ({...equip, [name]: value})));`